# L1 and L2 cache

Tags: computer-architecture, cpu-cache

I cannot find a to-the-point reference for my question. Am I correct in assuming that if you have an L1 and an L2 cache, typically  the L2 cache linesize is larger?

For the following, let's assume a word size of 1 byte, an array 'a'of one byte words, an L2 cache with blocksize of 8 bytes, and an L1 cache of 4 bytes.

So, if you try to access an element a[2] in an array, given that both caches are cold,  then a[0] - a[7] will be transferred to L2, and then a[0] - a[3] will be transferred to L1, and then a[2] can be sent to the register?

Comment: The L2 cache line must be at least as large as the L1 cache line, but in many cases (such as the current Intel Core series), the L1/L2 caches use the same sized cache line.  There is a much more detailed explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14707803/line-size-of-l1-and-l2-caches

Comment: Not all L2 caches use strict inclusion. AMD's Athlon L2 caches even used strict *exclusion* (i.e., L2 acted as a huge victim cache). It is not rare for outer levels of cache to use a larger line size, but recent x86 implementations seem to have chosen a single 64B line size for all levels (and do not use sectoring).

Comment: The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> *The cache line size is 64 Bytes. The size of the last-level cache varies
> a lot: 4MB per 2 Cores for Intel Core2 processor QX6850 and Intel Xeon
> processor 5300 series, 6MB per 2 Cores for Intel Core2 processor
> QX9770 and Intel Xeon processor 5400 series, 8MB per 4 cores for Intel
> Core i7-965 and Intel Xeon processor 5500 series.*
>
> Source: [Intel forums](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-threading-building-blocks/topic/296674)

You can also find few details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716145/where-is-the-l1-memory-cache-of-intel-x86-processors-documented) about Intel processors cache line size.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution.  However, this doesn't appear to answer the question that was asked.  As a reminder, the question asks whether  typically the L2 cache linesize is larger than the L1 cache linesize. That's a yes-or-no question, so any answer should start by answering yes or no and then providing explanation and justification of the answer.  I don't see that here.  Also, we don't want to be just a link farm with links to external sites.  Please see http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer and edit your answer.  Thank you!